# Подгрузка данных не по таймеру с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Можно посылать через определенное время AJAX запросы, соответственно получать ответ, и производить необходимые действия.. Чаще запросы - больше нагрузка на БД. Реже запросы - меньше интерактивности, т.е. палка о двух концах

Вопрос: Есть ли способ, подгрузить человеку на страницу данные, не через определенное время, а при другом событии? Допустим человек сидит на сайте, в какой то момент нужно подгрузить данные ( ну допустим состояние бд изменилось, или сообщение от другого пользователя )

Comment: @gforse Да вот только недавно был [вопрос](http://goo.gl/1EDcQM) про это. Пользуйтесь поиском. Почитайте про [WebSocket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). Далее, почитайте [мой ответ](http://goo.gl/Ydp2sj). В нём я указал про библиотеки на PHP, которые позволяют создавать event loop демон. Если предполагается приличная нагрузка, к примеру, браузерные игры, то посмотрите в сторону Node.js с их [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: @gforse А [здесь в комментариях](http://goo.gl/Vhg9fl) я описал возможные подводные камни с которыми скорее всего вы столкнётесь.